# How to select one to many related table's first instance's field as display template?

Tags: directus

I have 2 tables with these fields:

1. items (date, ...)
2. items_translations (title, ...)

I want to select `title` field of first `items_translations` as `display template` of `items` table. But I can only select `items_translations` table as a whole which shows `[1]` because of `one to many relationship`.

Is there any way to select only the first `items_translations`'s `title` field?

I use Directus 9.

[image]

As you can see, the `User Created` can be clicked, and then only one field can be selected. I think my question is a little bit weird but I think it is very often requested because of the translation table.